What protocol should I use to download large files?
I have an ESP32-based device connected to the Internet using WiFi.
Sometimes it needs to download a "large" file (200-300 MB) but it does not need to store it. Instead, it needs to send it via SPI to another device.
So,  my idea is:

Open a "stream" channel with the remote server
Download the file in chunks
When a chunk is downloaded send it over SPI
Continue until the whole file is downloaded and transmitted
Download and send the MD5 to the external device as well in order to check the integrity of the received file

I'm not expecting more than 10 devices downloading the same file at the same time. And no more than 30 devices downloading any file at the same time.
As a rough estimation, the SPI communication has a bandwith of less than 1 Mbit/s.
Ideally, it should also offer resume/progress features to easily restart from a specific byte if the connection drops.
Is there a ready-to-use protocol for this purpose or do I have to write a server application by myself? It will be a commercial device: I'm afraid SSL is mandatory here to provide enough protection, isnt'it?

SPI was likely created my chip manufactures to reduce pin counts on parts which needed to share data on the same PCB. Sending large amounts of data over wires more than a meter away is stretching its abilities. Because of this, there is little need to correct large amounts of data. As you are finding out. You are well on your way to fixing this except for ... step 6 (Receive back an ACK or NAC and transmit the next chunk for an ACK or transmit the last chunk for a NAK) ... step 7 (Place an upper limit on retries and fail the communications so as not to create a retry communications storm).

@st2000 who talked about meters away? :) the device is less than 50 mm from the MCU. It's is on the same PCB! My question is not about how to transfer data between MCU and the external device, but how to download a large file from the Internet using a protocol that allows me to decide how fast I can download the chunks

Of course you won't be using MD5 but SHA-256 or better...

I'm really curious as to what the scenario could possibly be which involves sending 200-300 MB over SPI. I suppose you have understood that it will take quite a long time to send all that data at that speed (probably an hour or more)? Honestly I don't think the problem is on the device-server side (though some servers or intermediate devices such as proxies/firewalls may balk at such a long connection), but rather on the SPI side. You need to add frame-level counters and checks and retransmits, and of course implement a sliding window mechanism.

@jcaron yes, I'm aware about the SPI issues, but I've already developed this part and it works. That's not matter of this question. About your curiosity, it is a special device that use audio files to make vibration tests and it needs to dowload new files from a server. Thanks for the hint about the integrity check with SHA-256.

" ... it is a special device that use audio files to make vibration tests and it needs to dowload new files from a server." ... I2S may be faster if you are transferring digital audio signals.

You might like to consider using https. It would mean not having to open
special ports, not having to invent a protocol, and being able to test at
one end with any of the available simple servers and at the other end using
curl or similar tools from a Linux pc etc. You probably already have code
to do http or https for your ESP32.
The http protocol has an optional header
Range
to request a given set of bytes from the url. For example, as shown in the
linked article, if you add option -H 'Range: bytes=100-199' to a curl
command you will get 100 bytes back, starting from offset 100. You also get
some http headers that you need to skip over until you see \r\n\r\n. Note that unlike a normal
request the http code is not "200 OK" but "206 Partial Content".
$ curl -s -0 -H 'Range: bytes=100-199' -o /tmp/out https://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg
$ ls -l /tmp/out
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 100 Nov 20 18:36 /tmp/out


Great! So I can ask for the file length first. Then I can issue sequential reads using the Range header until file ends.

Yes. Sending a HEAD request as opposed to a GET will reply with just the headers, including the Content-Length: of the file, and if the server supports ranges you would normally also get a Accept-Ranges: header. For the first request you could always ask for the whole file, and let the data queue up over the tcp connection. You might only need to ask for a range to resume if the connection was lost due to network problems or the server (or the esp32 software defaults) timing out the connection.

Note that the server must support it. Standard web servers such as Apache support it for static files, but if the contents are served by a script (CGI, php…) then the script must support it.
